# I need to make a copy of an array of cards, but I am only given the address of the array I need to copy

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I need to make a temporary copy of an array of cards that I do not have direct access to because it is in another class named Hand. I am given a method called getHand() which returns the reference to the array I need a copy of in the class RummyHand which is a subclass of Hand. The variable rummyHand is an instance variable in the RummyHand class and is a Hand object. Also I am working in eclipse if that matters.

but neither this:

> Card[] temp = new Card[8];
>
> temp = rummyHand.getHand();

or this:

> Card[] temp = rummyHand.getHand();

has copied the array like I thought it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf) or [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy an array, or, more simply, clone():

```
Card[] temp = rummyHand.getHand().clone();
```

Note that using the `=` operator never *copies* any data. All `=` does is make a variable refer to a different thing. This is important to understand because otherwise it will cause you a lot of trouble down the road.

In (hopefully useful) detail:

```
new Card[8];
```

creates an array: a new area of memory big enough to hold pointers to 8 cards.

```
Card[] temp
```

creates a variable that must point to some kind of array of cards. The

```
=
```

in the middle makes the variable point to that area of memory. The expression

```
rummyHand.getHand();
```

supplies you with the address of a different area of memory. So the line

```
temp = rummyHand.getHand();
```

just makes the `temp` variable point to that area of memory instead. `copyOf`, `arrayCopy` and `clone` all work by creating a new array and filling it with the references from the original array, then handing you back the new array.

Comment: There are easier ways - cloning or java.util.Arrays, for example.

Comment: @gustafc You're quite right. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) to copy an array:

```
Card[] temp = rummyHand.getHand().clone();
```

This will give you an exact copy of the same length as the original. If you want the copy eight elements long regardless of the length of the original, you can use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29):

```
Card[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(rummyHand.getHand(), 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to copy an array. The most basic is to create an array of the same size as the source array, then loop over the elements of the source array and add each one to your new copy:

```
Card[] source = rummyHand.getHand();
Card[] temp = new Card[source.length];

// for loop:
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
    temp[i] = source[i];
```

But there are java utility classes that will do this for you. See [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5b%5d,%20int%29):

```
Card[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(source, source.length);
```

But note that your new array will contain the same `Card` references as the source array, meaning that any changes to the objects in the array *won't* change copies: they'll change the actual object. If you need copies of the *contents* of the array, then you'll need to use the loop, and make a copy of each `Card` before adding it to the `temp` array.

When you're doing: `temp = rummyHand.getHand();`, you're getting a reference to the original array, *not* a copy, and so any changes that you make will change the array in the `rummyHand` object..

Comment: Why not use System.arraycopy()? It is much faster.

Comment: @Robert faster than what? note that I mention `Arrays.copyOf`. I've included the for loop for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Card[] hand = rummyHand.getHand();
Card[] temp = new Card[hand.length()];
System.arraycopy(hand,0,temp,0,hand.length());
```

Afterwards you have a copy of the array - but keep in mind that the references to the cards in the array are still the same. Therefore if you change a property of a card in `temp` it will also change the card in `hand` as both arrays contain the same "card instances".